# How do i implement IOHIDEventDriver use SystemExtension

Tags: macos, kernel-extension, driverkit

I have a old project, use the kext and IOHIDEventDriver:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDFamily-315.7.16/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDEventDriver.h.auto.html

https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDFamily-247/IOHIDFamily/IOHIDEventDriver.cpp.auto.html

I want to convert it to dext(publicly shown in WWDC 2019).

In Xcode11 beta7, I found some class in HIDDriverKit, USBDriverKit and DriverKit, but i don't know how to use it.